# AMAZON.HelpIntent is a built-in intent and cannot have slots

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

When I tried to update my intents, I'm getting this error. I need to use slot values for the `HelpIntent`. Please advice.

`ask api update-model --skill-id amzn1.ask.skill.abcd -f en-IN.json -l en-IN`

```
    Call update-model error.
    Error code: 400
    {
      "message": "Interaction model is not valid.",
      "violations": [
        {
          "message": "InvalidIntentSlot: Intent \"AMAZON.HelpIntent\" 
             is a built-in intent and cannot have slots."
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you cannot add slots to any of the Standard Built-in Intents like **`AMAZON.HelpIntent`**, `AMAZON.CancelIntent`, `AMAZON.NextIntent`, see the [full list](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/standard-built-in-intents.html)

These intents **do not use slots, and you cannot add slots** to them. However, you can extend the standard built-in intents by providing additional sample utterances. This is useful for invoking the intents with skill-specific utterances.

If you still want to use slots, create a custom help intent, which is not recommended.